# How to remove time delay in image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive recently been trying to teach myself jquery and javascript and saw an online tutorial on sliders, i have the below javascript/jquery code which works in principle but not exactly how i want.

In the tutorial example there is a gap between each image so the image slides off the screen, there is a gap then the next image slides in, i dont want any gap.  can anyone point me in the right direction please ?  thanks in advance!

by the way i changed `"$(".slider #1").show("slide",{direction:"left"},1500);"` from `$(".slider #1").show(0);` which is what it was in the tutorial to see if it would work but it didnt.

```
sliderint=1;
slidernext=2;

$(document).ready(function () 
{

    function Slider() {

        $(".slider #1").show("slide",{direction:"left"},1500);
        $(".slider #1").delay(1800).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},1500);



        var sc = $(".slider img").size();
        var count = 2;

        setInterval(function () {
            $(".slider #" + count).show("slide",{direction:"left"},1500);
            $(".slider #" + count).delay(1800).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},1500);

            if (count == sc) {
                count = 1;
            }
            else {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        },4800);
    }
    Slider();
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your `html` code? Or maybe create a fiddle for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=iJVIlj2UA6  hoping this works, apologies if it doesnt

Comment: erm not sure what happened but the title of my post is not what i typed.  if its not clear, i am trying to remove the whitespace inbetween each image as one slides out and the next slides in